# What happens to $\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(1-s)$ at $s=2,4,6,...$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

People on this website in many questions regarding functional equation of the zeta function keep telling that the singularities of the gamma function cancels with the zeros of the sin. What does it mean? How do they cancel? How the product of something that is zero with something that is not defined is a finite non-zero number.

And most importantly what Are the numerical answers at those points.

Comment: Shouldn't $s$ be $1, 3, 5, \ldots$?

Comment: No, I need it to be 2,4,6,8...

Comment: Since you tagged [tag:complex-analysis]: The even negative integers are *removable singularities* of the function $s \mapsto \Gamma(1-s)\cdot \sin \frac{\pi s}{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euler's Reflection Formula: $$\Gamma(1-s)\Gamma(s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$$

$$\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s)=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(s)}$$

Using the Sine Double Angle Formula: $$\Gamma(1-s)2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(s)}$$

$$\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})=\frac{\pi}{2}\sec(\frac{\pi s}{2})\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$$

Now you can determine the values as $s\to2n$ since the expression on the righthand side is defined for even integers.

Comment: But we cannot plug integers into reflection fromula so how does it work?

Comment: There are actually removable singularities at the negative even integers, since the secant expression is defined for those values. For example, the limit as $s\to2$ is -$\frac{\pi}{2}$ if you do the math.

Comment: Of course. i failed to spot it. Thank ypu

Comment: @KuderaSebastian $\Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s), \Gamma(1)=1$ shows that when $s \to 2n$ the zero of $\sin(\pi s/2)$ annihilates the pole of $\Gamma(1-s)$, to give something like $\lim_{s \to 2n} \sin(\pi s/2) \Gamma(1-s) = (-1)^n \frac{\pi /2}{(2n-1)!}$. Together with $\zeta(1-2n) = \frac{-B_{2n}}{2n}$ it gives [the result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers)